# UITextView UIPickerView keyboard animation issues

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, uipickerview, uiviewanimation

I have been scratching my head to fix this. I have a `UITableView` having `UITextView` and `UIPickerView` as follows:
1. Each row has a `UITextView`
2. Last row has a `UITextView` and an non editable `UITextField` which opens up a `UIPickerView`

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

The control with text **All** is the `UITextField` which opens up a `UIPickerView`.

Following are the issues I am facing while animating them :
1. On resigning `UITextView`, `UITableView` scrolls to the top (it should scroll to the `UITextView` position). Tried with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`, still not helping.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    txtViewActive = nil;
    [self animateTextView:NO];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [txtUser resignFirstResponder];
    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"write_a_reply", nil)]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    [self animateTextView:YES];
}  

- (void) animateTextView: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 140;
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f;

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.superview.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.superview.frame, 0, movement);
    [tableMessageDetail scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathScrollTo
                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                                      animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

2. The way I am creating `UIPickerView`, I am not able to animate when keyboard appears.

   ```
   txtUser = [[UITextField alloc]init];
   UIToolbar *toolbarUsers = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];  
   [toolbarUsers setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];  
   [toolbarUsers sizeToFit];  
   UIBarButtonItem *flexButtonUsers = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
   UIBarButtonItem *doneButtonUsers =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];  
   NSArray *itemsArrayUsers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButtonUsers, doneButtonUsers, nil];  
   [toolbarUsers setItems:itemsArrayUsers];  
   [txtUser setInputAccessoryView:toolbarUsers];  
   arrUsers = [NSMutableArray new];  
   [arrUsers addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"all", nil)];  
   [arrUsers addObject:[[message.MessageByFirstName componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0]];  
   pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 150, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
   [pickerView setDataSource: self];  
   [pickerView setDelegate: self];  
   pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;  
   txtUser.inputView = pickerView;
   ```

I am looking for a stable solution where :

> - `UITextView` and `UIPickerView` keyboard animations won't clash (double animation in case user taps `UITextView` first and then `UITextField`)
> - `UIPickerView` animation

Probably `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` are handy but I am not able to use them cleanly.

Comment: Doesn't UITableView handle UI movements on keyboard appearance? Can you try without any manual animation and see?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager library to solve your keyboard issues. Download this library and place that folder into your project no need to import any class it will automatically handle your keyboard.

No need to remove pickerview in textViewDidBeginEditing method.

Just try to following below code.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [self.PickerVw removeFromSuperview];
   txtAge.inputView = self.PickerVw;
 }

 -(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
     arr1 = [NSMutableArray new];
     if (textField.tag == 1)
     {
       int min =  9;
       int max = 100;
       for (int i = min ; i < max; i++)
       {
          [arr1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(i+1)]];
       }
       [textView becomeFirstResponder];
       self.picker.tag = 1;
      }
      [self.picker reloadAllComponents];
 }
```

I hope this will help you. If you have still any doubts then let me know.